Circle vs rectangle collision detection
I have tried to implement circle vs rectangle collision detection in typescript as shown in this answer:
Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)
It seems to work when the circle intersects the rectangle from a side (hitting a wall), but when it intersects with a corner of the rectangle the collision seems to be detected too late and then it continues to spam collision when moving "inside" of the rectangle.
public collidedWithRectangle(other: Rectangle) {
  const rectMidX = other.width / 2;
  const rectMidY = other.height / 2;

  const distanceX = Math.abs(this.x - (other.x + rectMidX));
  const distanceY = Math.abs(this.y - (other.y + rectMidY));

  if (!(distanceX > (rectMidX + (this.diameter / 2)) ||
        distanceY > (rectMidY + (this.diameter / 2))))
    if (distanceY <= rectMidY) {
      this.speed.x = -this.speed.x;
      console.log(`A circle collided with a rectangle's side wall (${this.x}, ${this.y}, ${distanceX}, ${distanceY})`);
      return true;
    } else if (distanceX <= rectMidX) {
      this.speed.x = -this.speed.x;
      this.speed.y = -this.speed.y;
      console.log(`A circle collided with a rectangle's top or bottom wall (${this.x}, ${this.y}, ${distanceX}, ${distanceY})`);
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}

May this have something to do with how I update objects' positions? speed.x and speed.y is never bigger then 1 though.
this.x += this.speed.x;
this.y += this.speed.y;

EDIT:
I wander if the window.requestAnimationFrame is the correct way to update my game loop and if this does not have something to do with this bug. Here is my game loop code:
private gameLoop() {
  this.update();
  this.draw();

  this.animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.gameLoop.bind(this));
}


Try this

@MBo But your answer only checks for the case when the rectangle is inside of the circle. It does not reference the corner case present in my question.

My solution does also difference between left-right side collision and bottom-top (which is important in my case).

Less concise version might be modified to recognize touch side or corner (inside if's)

Also note  - it is better to precalculate collision moment than check collision at every time interval

@MBo Both objects are in motion, so I don't think this is possible to precalculate.

If they move straight with constant speed -  it is possible.

@MBo They move according to user input and reacts to simple physics.

@MBo I have implemented your example in typescript and it seems to work the same, with the same bag occurring. It makes me think it have something to do with how HTML5 canvas update interval works, as I use the window.requestAnimationFrame API. (https://paste.debian.net/1315960/)

How it works (Delphi function): https://i.sstatic.net/oTPr38mA.gif

@MBo Yes, I think your algorithm is awesome, it have rather something to do with optimization of canvas. I have counted the FPS now and (if my calculation is right) it returns Infinity. So I will try to buffer it down to 60 and see if this helps.

Apparently the fps argument problem was caused by passing the window.requestAnimationFrame argument as a lambda not a binding as mentioned here. I update the question to match the correct way.

I suspect that HTML5 canvas problems require separate question, this one looks like algorithmic.

@Mbo I think then I delete this question and create a new one, since the problem seems to be somewhere completely else in the code, and editing this one will just result in more confusion

Yes, it would be fine
